# How to use grunt-uncss with Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, optimization, grunt

When I'm running "grunt uncss" I have the following error :

```
Fatal error: PhantomJS: Cannot open about:blank
```

Here is my Gruntfile.js :

```
uncss: {
          dist: {
            files: {
                'css/styles.min.css': ['../../../../app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/*']
            }
          }
        }
```